# Yosemite install app won't download after being corrupted

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, crash

I tried to download the Yosemite install app and make a bootable usb with Diskmaker X but it failed and told me the install file became corrupted. This caused an endless Finder crash loop that I could only fix by deleting the Install file from the bash prompt in single user mode.

Now the app store shows "an error has occurred" and I can't download the app at all:
[image: 1]

I tried deleting the app store cache to no avail, now I'm stuck. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks

Comment: Congrats on finding out the answer to your issue :) - Something you can do here is add it as an answer to your own question, and then mark it accepted for the benefit of anyone else that comes along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it usually goes I figured it out shortly after posting. I previously hid it from my purchases and going into my account settings (Store > View My Account) and un-hiding it did the trick.